# How do I use random numbers to generate truly random results? ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID))) is not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Each time I run a query I need different results.

If I

```
SELECT AccountNumber
FROM TABLE
```

with no other specifications, the table returns the records in order of account number by default (i have no control over this).

My solution (I thought) was to

```
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) [RandomNumber], AccountNumber
INTO #tempTABLE
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY [RandomNumber]
```

So a whole new table gets built ordered by the randomly generated numbers. Then I could just

```
SELECT TOP 1 AccountNumber
FROM #tempTABLE
```

What I'm finding is there is a very high probability that the lowest random number will correlate with the lowest accountnumber. In short, this random number strategy is giving the same results very frequently. I need the results of my query to be a different, randomly selected account number each time i run it.

Comment: Truly random: [HotBits](https://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/).

Comment: "different" and "randomly selected" are somewhat contradictory. There is no reason why lowest  `ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID()))` would  be correlated with lowest  account number though.

Comment: @MartinSmith hence my quandry. Thank you for your consideration. In a pool of several hundred thousand accountnumbers, there's no reason I should get the same (lowest) account number frequently.

Comment: Have you actually *checked* the numbers or are you just assuming that `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` from the temp table will give you the lowest number? If so that's where you are going wrong. Firstly the `ORDER BY` will be ignored in the `SELECT INTO` as meaningless and secondly `SELECT` without `ORDER BY` doesn't guarantee anything about the order  they are returned in.

Comment: @MartinSmith you are correct, sir. My Order By was with the wrong select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the order by to your (2nd) select query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 AccountNumber
FROM #tempTABLE
ORDER BY [RandomNumber]
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a shortcut, you could simply order by a generated guid.

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
    AccountNumber
FROM 
   TABLE
ORDER BY
    NewID()
```